# sql using two or more OR conditions in a select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

AM trying to get status where status is not=16 or not=11 so basically i would like to get records with statuses

```
1 to 10 jump 11, then 12 to 15
```

This is my sql statement

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM tbl_trucks t
   WHERE t.truck_status != 11
   OR t.truck_status != 16;
```

In the above case only the second one is executed(!16).

I have also tried

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM tbl_trucks t
  WHERE t.truck_status <> 11
  OR t.truck_status <> 16
```

what could be wrong?

Comment: I guarantee the status will not equal 11 or not equal 16. A step back to understand basic boolean logic might be in order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM tbl_trucks t
WHERE t.truck_status NOT IN (11, 16);
```

Your code would work with `AND` instead of `OR`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong logic. If you want to NOT show status `11` and `16` it means that you want everything that isn't 11 AND isn't 16 so:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM tbl_trucks t
 WHERE t.truck_status <> 11
   AND t.truck_status <> 16
```

Comment: argh i see i think am abit tired thats why i made so basic mistake, Thanks.

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI please consider in accepting an answer. Please accept the one from Gordon, it is right, it is simpler and it was first.